# How to drag and drop multiple items to multiple spaces in a grid layout?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, inventory

So I've been trying to create an inventory style grid where you can drag and drop items of different sizes onto a set grid. I'm no expert with javascript/jquery but, with some help from other answers here, I currently have the drag and drop working, stackable items and some buggy form of grouping the items.

The idea with the grouped item was to have the image of the item anchored to the first (top left) item covering the others in the group - the others would basically be hidden but the image would cover that area. I'd need them (hidden items within the group) to occupy/be attached to a grid space so I could record that in a database and know what slots that item takes up no matter of the size.

The main solution I need is a way to group items for dragging and have them all drop in the spaces they are closest to (or revert to their original position if all can't go there). So it's like a tetris style game inventory.

In the fiddle below you can see how the grouped items currently work. If you drag the top blue box that will snap into place and the other will be below it but I don't think it is actually attached to that space and I need to send the data to a DB. Also if you dropped that into a space on the bottom row then it will snap but that would be wrong as the other is out of the inventory area.

After this I plan to add rotation but that's a different problem!

I've been at this in my spare time for a couple of weeks now and haven't figured it out. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: This is using jquery draggable and droppable

EDIT: TL DR: I need to be able to drag and drop items of different sizes that can take up multiple grid spaces (and snap to them). Currently the group dragging doesn't actually work for that. Try dragging the blue squares around a little and you should see the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/qxpnnya9/1/

```
<style>
#panel
{
    width: 340px;
    height: 44px;
    padding: 4px;
}

.inv_slot
{
    z-index: 22;
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}

.inv_slot .slot_pos{
    z-index: 24;
    position: absolute; 
    margin-left: 50%; 
    left: -4px; top: 2px;
}

.item
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 25;
    margin: 4px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#000000;
}

.item.stackable
{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
</style>

<div id="panel">
        <div class="inv_slot" data-item_count="1">
            <div class="item stackable"  data-item_count="1"><span class="item-count" data-item_count="1">1</span></div>
            <span class="slot_pos"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="inv_slot">
            <div class="item group1 group_check" data-item_count="1"><span class="item-count" data-item_count="1">1</span></div>
            <span class="slot_pos"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="inv_slot">
            <div class="item stackable" data-item_count="1"><span class="item-count" data-item_count="1">1</span></div>
            <span class="slot_pos"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="inv_slot"><span class="slot_pos"></span> </div>
        <div class="inv_slot"><span class="slot_pos"></span> </div>
        <div class="inv_slot"><span class="slot_pos"></span> </div>
        <div class="inv_slot"><span class="slot_pos"></span> </div>
        <div class="inv_slot"><span class="slot_pos"></span> </div>
        <div class="inv_slot" data-item_count="1">
            <div class="item stackable"  data-item_count="1"><span class="item-count" data-item_count="1">1</span></div>
            <span class="slot_pos"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="inv_slot">
            <div class="item group1 group_check" data-item_count="1"><span class="item-count" data-item_count="1">1</span></div>
            <span class="slot_pos"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="inv_slot">
            <div class="item stackable" data-item_count="1"><span class="item-count" data-item_count="1">1</span></div>
            <span class="slot_pos"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="inv_slot"><span class="slot_pos"></span> </div>
        <div class="inv_slot"><span class="slot_pos"></span> </div>
        <div class="inv_slot"><span class="slot_pos"></span> </div>
        <div class="inv_slot"><span class="slot_pos"></span> </div>
        <div class="inv_slot"><span class="slot_pos"></span> </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function() {
    var top_count = 0;
    //var prev_el = '';
    var group = 0; 
    var item_isStackable = "";
        // function to get matching groups (change '.group' and /group.../ inside the match to whatever class you want to use
    var getAll = function(t) {
        return $('.group' + t.helper.attr('class').match(/group([0-9]+)/)[1]).not(t);
    };
    $( ".item").draggable({
        scroll: true,
        revert: function(isValidEl)
        {
            if(isValidEl)
            {
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        },
        helper: "clone",
        stop: function(e, ui) {
            if(group == 1) {
                getAll(ui).css({
                    'top': ui.helper.css('top'),
                    'left': 0
                });
            }
        },
        cursor: "pointer",
        stack: false,
        zIndex: 27,
        drag: function(event, ui)
        {
            if($(this).hasClass('group_check')) {
                group = 1;
            } else {
                group = 0;  
            }

            item_isStackable = $(this).hasClass("stackable");
            top_count = $(this).attr("data-item_count");
            if(group == 1) {
                getAll(ui).css({
                    'top': ui.helper.css('top'),
                    'left': ui.helper.css('left')
                });  
            }
        },
    });
    $( ".inv_slot" ).droppable({
        accept: ".item",
        drop: function( event, ui ) { 
            var item = $(this).find(".item"); 
            if(group == 1) {
             ui.draggable.appendTo($(this));
             getAll(ui).appendTo($(this));
            }
            //alert (JSON.stringify($(ui))); 
            if(item.length == 0) /// See if there any items already in the currently selected inventory slot  // 
            {
                console.log("Inserting");
                ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this)); // if none, insert the item into athe free slot /// 
            }
            else if(item_isStackable == true && item.hasClass("stackable") && ui.draggable.filter(function() { return this == item[0]; }).length === 0) {
                    console.log("Increasing "); 
                    var bottom_count = $(this).find(".item").attr("data-item_count");

                    var new_count = parseFloat(top_count) + parseFloat(bottom_count);
                    $(this).find(".item").attr("data-item_count", new_count );
                    $(this).find("span").text(new_count);
                    ui.draggable.detach(); /// If yes, just destroy the clone /// 
            }else{
                console.log("reverting back");
                // in case it's not .inv_slot , revert the item back to it's previous position //
                ui.draggable.animate(ui.draggable.data().origPosition,"slow");  
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what/where exactly is your problem

Comment: So if you go on to the fiddle and drag the blue squares they are grouped and drag together but they don't both attach to the space they are dragged to, only the only you have clicked and dragged does not the one attached. To be able to record in a DB all the positions, so I know when a space is full, I need it to attach to the empty space. If all spaces that all the grouped items are hovering either aren't empty or aren't a space then it should revert to it's original position.

It's like the grouping works aesthetically but not functionally. Hope that clears things up a little.

Comment: @Dekel sorry forgot to tag you back. I think i'm trying to over explain, I've added a TD LR to the post, hopefully that's a little more to the point, thanks.